Creating loops to pull data from different worksheets using VBA?
I'm new to VBA code. I'm trying to create a loop where I copy cells E8:E16 from 6 different worksheets and past them into a "master" work sheet. This range does not change at all. I'm having trouble when it comes to pasting the values into the "master" worksheet. I would like the pasted values to start and end at C4:C12, then D4:D12, etc. Can anyone help? Here is the code I currently have:
Sub WeekpayLoop()

Dim ws As Worksheet

    For Each ws In Worksheets
        If ws.Name <> "Praticeruns" Then
            ws.Range("E8:E16").Copy
            ActiveSheet.Paste Range("C4:C12")
        End If
    Next ws

End Sub

The only success I've gotten so far was using this code:
Old VBA Code
However, when I run this code the formatting is off as all copied values are listed in column A.

Please don't include code as an image - you can copy/paste as text.

If you just need to move the paste destination over to the right for each sheet:
Sub WeekpayLoop()

    Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet, rngPaste As Range

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook  'or ActiveWorkbook, etc
    
    'start pasting here...
    Set rngPaste = wb.Worksheets("Praticeruns").Range("C4")
    
    Debug.Print "Checking workbook: " & wb.Name
    For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
        If ws.Name <> rngPaste.Parent.Name Then
            Debug.Print ,"Worksheet: " & ws.Name
            ws.Range("E8:E16").Copy rngPaste
            Set rngPaste = rngPaste.Offset(0, 1) 'next column to the right
        End If
    Next ws

End Sub


Thank you for your comment! I just tried using you code, but nothing happens when I run it. Suggestions?

Are the source and destination worksheets in the same workbook as the code?  If not, then which workbook are they in?  Have you tried stepping through the code using F8?

Made a few edits above and added some Debug.Print output (check in the VB editor Immediate pane for the results)

My apologies for the late response, we've been swamped at work. I've set aside majority of today to get this code running. Thank you for the F8 tip, I have done this with your new code and there does not seem to be any issues, however I still can not get the code to paste properly on "Praticeruns" ws. And all source and destination worksheets are in the same workbook

Unfortunately all of it is sensitive data. I will mimic my spreadsheet with false data and send it your way. Thanks for your help!

I actually just found a very stupid mistake (usually how things go), everything is working!!! If I have any other questions, I will be sure to reach out. Thanks again for all your help!

OK good to hear you got it working.  Please flag as "Accepted" if this answered your question, to help out anyone coming along later with a similar problem.
